# Make JSON from li strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
<div class="col-xs-4 no-padding contenteditable-color" style="background-color: transparent;">
     <ul class="ul-product">
         <li class="li-product-page cars contenteditable" contenteditable="false">qweryt</li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 no-padding contenteditable-color" style="background-color: transparent;">
     <ul class="ul-product">
         <li class="li-product-page cars contenteditable" contenteditable="false">bbzzz</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I have multiple li and I want to get all and to make JSON with name 'cars'. I've tried something like this but won't work

```
$("li.cars").each(function() {
    var obj = {
        keywords: $("li.keywords").text()
    }
});
```

I want to send this JSON to server with AJAX.

**EDIT**

Here is the ajax

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standard javascript object here
            var data = new FormData(form);
                data.append('car', brand);
                data.append('keywords', arr);


            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url:'myurl',
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                cache: false,
                contentType:false,
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);


                },
                 error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
                 }

            })
```

Comment: You want them in a single array or each car in it's own object?

Comment: @Tushar please make that an answer so that I can +1 it

Comment: @Tushar when I'm sending this object with ajax. On request payload I have [object object]

Comment: @driveaferrari Because the object is casted into string it is printing `[object Object]`. Make sure you're not concatenating it to string.

Comment: @Tushar i've comed with an update..with how my ajax looks

Comment: Try `data.append('keywords', JSON.stringify(arr))`

Comment: @Tushar the problem is ..in database I have "keywords":"mystring" ...it's all like a string..and when I'm trying to show the items on my page..it comes like this .. <li>"keywords":"mystring"</li>

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object and in its keywords key make an array of li values:

```js
var obj = {keywords:[]};
$( "li.cars" ).each(function() {
      obj.keywords.push($(this).text());
 });
 console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-4 no-padding contenteditable-color" style="background-color: transparent;">
     <ul class="ul-product">
         <li class="li-product-page cars contenteditable" contenteditable="false">qweryt</li>
     </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 no-padding contenteditable-color" style="background-color: transparent;">
     <ul class="ul-product">
         <li class="li-product-page cars contenteditable" contenteditable="false">bbzzz</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

It will give you something like so:

```
{keywords: ["someval","anotherval"]}
```

You can simply send the obj variable o the backend and json decode it at the backend.

When you want to send it to the server you can stringify it like so:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: I want to send this obj var with ajax..but on request payload I have [object Object]

Comment: use `var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);` let me update the answer for you

Comment: if I do that it will put in my database all JSON as string...not as JSON

Comment: No it won't are you using AJAX ?

Comment: @ Shakti Phartiyal yes, i'm using AJAX...i will come with an update...to see the ajax

Comment: If you use your backend language as PHP you can decode the string you got as `json_decode(THE_VARIABLE,true);` to get back your desired result.

Comment: And how can I do to put every element with his object?..Somethig like {keywords: ["someval"]} {keywords: ["anotheerradwa"]} {keywords: ["xxsaas"]}

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = [];

$('ul').children().each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var item = { id: $this.attr('value'), title: $this.html() };
  items.push(item);
});
```

Try This One...